# How to have a good "ComboBox" In HTML

Tags: php, html, combobox, html-select, html-datalist

I need a simple<sup>*</sup>, yet utilizable<sup>**</sup> *"[combo box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box)"* that can provide me with the `value` of the selected entry; or with the content of the arbitrary text entered together with a predefined `value` (e.g: `0` to indicate the out-of-list entrance) when it has been submitted. I can't find a good solution; Please help me out :)

---

To elaborate more on the case, consider the following code:

```
<select name="code">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Using the aforementioned structure, I can get the `code` with the associate `value` in PHP; it's nice, but it's not enough though! I also need to let the user enter any arbitrary string and get that arbitrary string in PHP, probably with a predefined custom `value` of `0` to indicate the entered value is not in the list.

The `<datalist>` also does not fit well, as it has different implementations across browsers, some of which also undesirably put the content of the `value` in the input box.

---

<sup>* By *"simple"* I mean it to have the minimum possible dependencies.</sup>
<sup>** And by *"utilizable"* I mean it to features like auto-complete, to be able to have the desired entry `selected`, etc.</sup>

Comment: something like this? https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: @Dale Thank you, I think my search instincts are dried!! How couldn't I find such a great tool?!! The feature I was looking for is called _"Dynamic option creation"_ that they call it `tagging`;  I really appreciate it :)